Not able to run my native image build with graalvm springboot image
i am trying to  migrate my project to use graalvm but having issue in running
I am using below dependencies in pom.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
       <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
       <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
       <version>3.3.5</version>
       <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.consumer.spring</groupId>
    <artifactId>splunk</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>splunk</name>
    <description>Splunk Framework</description>
    <url/>
    <licenses>
       <license/>
    </licenses>
    <developers>
       <developer/>
    </developers>
    <scm>
       <connection/>
       <developerConnection/>
       <tag/>
       <url/>
    </scm>
    <properties>
       <java.version>17</java.version>
       <solace-spring-cloud.version>4.5.0</solace-spring-cloud.version>
       <spring-cloud.version>2023.0.3</spring-cloud.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
       <dependency>
          <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
       </dependency>
       <dependency>
          <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-r2dbc</artifactId>
       </dependency>
       <dependency>
          <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-redis-reactive</artifactId>
       </dependency>
       <dependency>
          <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
       </dependency>
       <dependency>
          <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-cache</artifactId>
       </dependency>
       <dependency>
          <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-webflux</artifactId>
       </dependency>
       <dependency>
          <groupId>com.solace.spring.cloud</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-stream-solace</artifactId>
       </dependency>
       <dependency>
          <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-cloud-stream</artifactId>
       </dependency>

       <dependency>
          <groupId>org.mariadb</groupId>
          <artifactId>r2dbc-mariadb</artifactId>
          <version>1.1.3</version>
          <scope>runtime</scope>
       </dependency>
       <dependency>
          <groupId>org.mariadb.jdbc</groupId>
          <artifactId>mariadb-java-client</artifactId>
          <scope>runtime</scope>
       </dependency>
       <dependency>
          <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-data-commons</artifactId>
       </dependency>
       <dependency>
          <groupId>jakarta.activation</groupId>
          <artifactId>jakarta.activation-api</artifactId>
       </dependency>
       <dependency>
          <groupId>jakarta.xml.bind</groupId>
          <artifactId>jakarta.xml.bind-api</artifactId>
       </dependency>
       <dependency>
          <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.module</groupId>
          <artifactId>jackson-module-jakarta-xmlbind-annotations</artifactId>
          <version>2.18.1</version> <!-- Or the latest compatible version -->
       </dependency>
       <dependency>
          <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
          <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
       </dependency>
       <dependency>
          <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat</groupId>
          <artifactId>jackson-dataformat-xml</artifactId>
       </dependency>
       <dependency>
          <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.module</groupId>
          <artifactId>jackson-module-jaxb-annotations</artifactId>
          <version>2.14.0</version>
       </dependency>



       <dependency>
          <groupId>org.glassfish.jaxb</groupId>
          <artifactId>jaxb-runtime</artifactId>
       </dependency>

       <dependency>
          <groupId>org.glassfish.jaxb</groupId>
          <artifactId>jaxb-xjc</artifactId>
       </dependency>
       <dependency>
          <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
          <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
          <scope>provided</scope>
       </dependency>
       <dependency>
          <groupId>io.projectreactor</groupId>
          <artifactId>reactor-test</artifactId>
          <scope>test</scope>
       </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <dependencyManagement>
       <dependencies>
          <dependency>
             <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
             <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
             <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
             <type>pom</type>
             <scope>import</scope>
          </dependency>
          <dependency>
             <groupId>com.solace.spring.cloud</groupId>
             <artifactId>solace-spring-cloud-bom</artifactId>
             <version>${solace-spring-cloud.version}</version>
             <type>pom</type>
             <scope>import</scope>
          </dependency>
       </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
       <plugins>
          <plugin>
             <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
             <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
          </plugin>
        <plugin>
       <groupId>org.graalvm.buildtools</groupId>
       <artifactId>native-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    </plugin>
          <plugin>
             <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
             <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
             <version>3.8.0</version>
             <configuration>
                <source>${java.version}</source>
                <target>${java.version}</target>
             </configuration>
          </plugin>
       </plugins>
    </build>


</project>

mvn -Pnative native:compile
Always having issue while running native image application dont start
Have below exceptions
1.Not able to autoconfigure r2dbcentity
2.lettuceconnectionfactory
i am using springboot 3.3.5 and jdk 17
basically its not able to autoconfigure the beans
Please help
Tried to add reflection json
resource json
when i added explicitly nbean config for r2dbc the error related to r2dbc was gone but lettuceconnection factory error not going

According to this it is related to DNS configuration of windows, are you trying to run it in windows ?

yes @ozkanpakdil
